# User Control Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form and this form will load user control during run-time based on a user checkbox click:

If I click checkbox1, I will load usercontrol1

If I click checkbox2, I will load usercontrol2

```
if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked)
        {
            panel3.Controls.Clear();
            UC_Buttons_Operation uc_Operation = new UC_Buttons_Operation();
            panel3.Controls.Add(uc_Operation);
        }
```

How do I get the event from these user control(say a button) which I load during run time?

From what I search, I see exposing a public event from the UC and the main form will be able to see it. This is fine but problem is I am loading by run time. UC will not be created before hand.

```
public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;
public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wire up the event:

```
uc_Operation.ButtonClick += UCButtonClick;
```

and implement it:

```
void UCButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

If you look at the form designer code for existing controls you will see how your form implements its own button creation/event handling.

Comment: Because i am loading the UC during runtime, hence in main during design stage, the UC will not be there. Also i have a lots of cascading UC. Is there a easy way to open up the event from the lowest level for the top level to see?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if you programmatically create your UC, you can hook the events up (the handler will need to already exist of course), if you need a generic event handler then you could have each UC implement a given interface.  So in your code sample, before adding it to the panel, you'd wire up the events.

Comment: This is what i had done
The lowest UC is just a button with  a text i am exposing the event with `public event EventHandler ButtonClick;``        public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
`

Comment: I think i got what you mean. Thanks for the help. Please ignore my last comment